# Is it proper to start a sentence with the word that ended the last sentence?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, writing-style, sentence-starts, repetition

For example:

> Instead, you’ll use a higher-level model called ASP.NET AJAX. ASP.NET AJAX gives you a set of server-side components and controls that you can use when designing your web page.

This does not seem correct to me, at least in this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While I'm not aware of a particular grammatical rule that would prohibit this, as a matter of style, I would prefer not to do what you're suggesting there, especially with something like *ASP.NET AJAX*.  I would suggest something like:

> Instead, you’ll use a higher-level model called ASP.NET AJAX. This toolkit gives you a set of server-side components and controls that you can use when designing your web page.

You can replace *toolkit* with something more appropriate if you prefer.

Comment: I saw this in a book I am reading and decided it could make a decent question here.  I'd definitely like to know if there is a grammatical rule.

Comment: @Fosco: As Dusty says (correctly), there is no rule actually prohibiting this.  And, in the right situations, it can be done intentionally for added effect.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Excellent point.  As a rhetorical device, it could be quite helpful.

Answer (score 4):

It is a recognised [rhetorical device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anadiplosis). That said, when you are not going for rhetoric it may be best if you avoided it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You just did.

I don't know of any rule forbidding it and even if there was it likely is simply a best practice.

As with most things, avoid it if it makes the sentences hard to read or sound awkward, even if it is technically correct.

Comment: Ha ha.   Title has been updated.